# Java - XSS - HTML encoding - Character entity reference vs. Numeric entity reference

Tags: java, html, encoding, xss

We've been looking for ways to HTML encode our JSP pages to counter XSS.

The OWASP site shows [How_to_perform_HTML_entity_encoding_in_Java](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_perform_HTML_entity_encoding_in_Java)

The article talks about entity encoding the "Big 5" i.e.

```
  21          {"#39", new Integer(39)}, // ' - apostrophe
  22          {"quot", new Integer(34)}, // " - double-quote
  23          {"amp", new Integer(38)}, // & - ampersand
  24          {"lt", new Integer(60)}, // < - less-than
  25          {"gt", new Integer(62)}, // > - greater-than
```

i.e.

```
<script>
```

is encoded as

```
  &lt;script&gt;
```

but the Java code sample included in the article uses numeric reference encoding i.e.

```
<script></script>
```

is encoded as

```
 &#60;script&#62;&#60;&#47;script&#62;
```

Is there a reason for using character references over entity references? Which is best and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same as far as protecting yourself from XSS is concerned. The only real practical differences are readability and size.